# How to extend QDockWidget functions in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5, qdockwidget

I'm new to Qt, tried several widgets and found that QDockWidget is the most modern/interactive one to work with

But I've found a little limitation "about where to dock the widget only in the 4 sides, left/right/top/bottom"

I want to do one of the two following things and **any one should work**.

1. Add more areas to dock widget "for example it can recognize separators between widgets and get its data from there , then resize itself depending on that"
2. Reimplement the whole functions of QDockWidget into QWidget and do
   it like option 1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Qt you can pretty much inherit any class into a new class of your own and extend it yourself. for example:

```
// New class that inherits QDockWidget and extends its functionality
ExtendedQDockWidget : public QDockWidget
{
public:
    ExtendedQDockWidget(QWidget * parent = 0) : 
        QDockWidget(parent)
    {
        // ... do any extra initialisations here
    }

    ExtendedFunc(/* some params */)
    {
        // code here
    }
}
```

You can also re-implement or overload existing functions to do exactly what you want.

Comment: well I think I know this :D , I just wanted to know if there is any virtual functions out there to detect areas that I may override instead of writing the staff from scratch